# FactoryGirl creating multiple records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot

I'm trying to get in the habit of writing specs, however, this is becoming increasingly frustrating.

Assume I have two simple models: `User` and `Story`. Each model uses a `belongs_to` relation. Each model uses a `validates :foo_id, presence: true` as well.

However, FactoryGirl is creating multiple records.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    email "foo@bar.com"
    password "foobarfoobar"
  end # this creates user_id: 1

  factory :story do
    title "this is the title"
    body "this is the body"
    user # this creates user_id: 2
  end
end
```

This simple test fails:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Story do

  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  let(:story) { FactoryGirl.create(:story) }

  it 'should belong to User' do
    story.user = user
    expect(story.user).to eq(user)
  end
end
```

What am I missing here? I cannot build a `Story` factory without a `User`, yet I need it to be just one `User` record.

Comment: show the failing test report also..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The values you define for each attribute in a factory are only used if you don't specify a value in your `create` or `build` call.

```
user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
story = FactoryGirl.create(:story, user: user)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In hindsight, it seems pretty clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a feature of factory girl to create the associated user when you create the story.

You can avoid it like this:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Story do
  let(:story) { FactoryGirl.create(:story) }
  let(:user) { story.user }

  it 'should belong to User' do
    story.user.should eq user
  end
end
```

This example is setup to be trivially `true`, but you get the point.

Answer (score 1):

When doing something like this you can do:

```
let(:story) { FactoryGirl.create(:story, user: user) }
```

Or maybe you can only let the story variable and do:

```
let(:story) { FactoryGirl.create(:story, user: user) }
let(:user)  { User.last}
```